# Spring JMS DefaultMessageListener - onMessage() not getting invoked

Tags: spring

I am trying to implement a point-to-point messaging system using TIBCO EMS and Spring framework.

I am able to write a message to the queue, but the problem I am facing is in consuming the message.

I have written a Java class that implements the Spring DefaultMesssageListener class and used that within the applicationContext.xml file which is as shown below:

---

For consuming the message I have written a Java class which reads the above applicationContext.xml file. But, when I start the program I am not getting any error but at the same time message is not getting consumed.

Thank you,
Raghu

Answer (score 0):

You missed something important in configuring the queue, the listener, or the client.  Review [this](http://blog.springsource.com/2006/08/11/message-driven-pojos/) and see what you missed.